# Delete a file using awk

Tags: awk

In an awk script, can we  delete a file? For example: `outPut.txt` is a file and if some business logic fails I need to delete that file. I tried to delete but it is not deleting it.

Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Show us what you tried, and we can maybe help you fix it.  Hide what you tried, and we probably won't.  Also, why do you want to delete it from `awk`?  Why not do it the normal way, with the `rm` command?

Comment: There is no built-in command in standard Awk to access the `unlink()` system call if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

Something like `system("rm output.txt")` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should help you:

```
awk {'print $3'} | xargs /bin/rm -f
```